# Why I am getting the error "Unable to create a constant value of type.Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities

I am having a method in controller like below where I am trying to get boxes using lamda expression as follows

```
          public JsonResult GetBoxes(ICollection<BoxesViewModel> boxes)
          {
            try
              {
                var Box = ApplicationService.GetBoxes<Boxes>(b => b.Id == boxes.FirstOrDefault().Id).FirstOrDefault();
              }
          }
```

when i run the application with the above code I got the following exception
"Unable to create a constant value of type 'Test.Mvc4KendoWeb.Models.Boxes.BoxesViewModel'.
Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."

But when i modified the code like below it started working

```
          public JsonResult GetBoxes(ICollection<BoxesViewModel> boxes)
          {
            try
              {
                var BoxId = boxes.FirstOrDefault().Id;
                var Box = ApplicationService.GetBoxes<Boxes>(b => b.Id == BoxId).FirstOrDefault();
              }
          }
```

Now, my question is why i got the error, When i try to directly define the "Id" (boxes.FirstOrDefault().Id) inside the lamda expression.

I searched in net, But i didn't get the clear reason behind this. Please, help me on this.

Comment: Does `GetBoxes` make a DB query via entity framework? If so it will be because entity framework does not know about `BoxesViewModel` and therefore doesn't know what to do when it converts the lamba expression to SQL

Comment: yes, GetBoxes makes a DB query through EF. Thanks, I hope i got the exact answer which i need

Comment: I suppose because clr translate a delegate to Expression to store it in expression tree of query.
You can construct lambda expression by yourself and sent it to method:
    `ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Boxes), "o");`
`MemberExpression property = Expression.Property(parameter, key);`
`ConstantExpression equalsTo = Expression.Constant(...); // your equals constant here.`
`BinaryExpression equality = Expression.Equal(property, equalsTo);`

So because it is a constant you can't assign a method. P.S. sory, can't make a good format